# Can Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() return 0?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

Is there a particular condition in which `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` returns `0`? 
Maybe when all proccessors are busy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. According to the docs, `Runtime.availableProcessors()` can never return less than one.

> Returns:
>   The maximum number of processors available to the virtual machine; never smaller than one

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors()

Answer (score 2):

No.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors--

"the maximum number of processors available to the virtual machine; **never smaller than one**"